# Prevent new line in rows in mPDF

Tags: phalcon, mpdf, volt

I am trying to make an A4 page with mPDF with 20 lines. It should always fit on one page with the same font size and line height. The text in each line can vary in length. If it's too long, I just want to strip it at the end.
I tried with white-space:nowrap with no luck, the text keeps going in a new line. Tried with tables, divs, multiple elements.

My mpdf configuration:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
  'mode' => 'utf-8',
  'format' => 'A4',
  'margin_left' => 0,
  'margin_right' => 0,
  'margin_top' => 0,
  'margin_bottom' => 0,
  'margin_header' => 0,
  'margin_footer' => 0
  ]);
```

My template:

```
<style>
    table {
        padding: 0 3%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table td {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 46px;
    }
</style>

<table autosize="1">
    {% for i in 1..20 %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{i}}.  Text of varying length (if it's short the rows are ok, but not if it's long)
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Would appreciate any help of suggestions what I may be doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: In a case like this it is important to use a monospace font. Get the maximum number of characters that can fit per line. Then, in Volt, add a conditional to limit the number of characters per line.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have dynamic text length, and dynamic number of rows, so limiting the number of characters won't work.

Comment: I had a similar project, we needed pixel precision because the result was going to be printed in pre-printed forms: always, before inserting the line, the length of the string was controlled: in our case, over 45 characters it was truncated; the monospace font was essential for achieving this.

Comment: This seems like a less than ideal solution :/

Comment: Proven and works. If you find a better one, please share it.

Comment: Yes, it works for mocospace fonts (which we don't have), also for fixed number of rows. we havy dynamic number of rows, so we would have to change string length for each number of rows, because font size is different for let's say 10 rows, or 20 rows. for 30 rows it's smaller

Comment: Could you share an image with the result that you expect? You can also highlight what you want to avoid.

Comment: And could this be of help? And, could this be of  help? https://codefrontend.com/css-ellipsis/